# Under the hood of Clojure repl execution

Tags: clojure, clojure-repl

I understand Clojure code is compiled into classes and executed by JVM. For a Java project, I'm able to see a Jar gets created with `.class` files in it. But how exactly it works in case of a REPL?

Comment: Nowadays you can generate bytecode and load classes during runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clojure code is [compiled](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java) using the [ASM library](https://asm.ow2.io/) into class files. Those class files are loaded into a custom [DynamicClassLoader](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/DynamicClassLoader.java).

Good talk on the compilation process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Qm09YiUHTs